# Pixelated japanese characters on NixOS

Tags: fonts, nixos

I recently installed NixOS 22.11, with Gnome desktop environment, but all japanese characters look pixelated, like shown in the picture:

[image]

My configuration file is as follows:

```json
fonts = {
  enableDefaultFonts = true;

  fonts = with pkgs; [
    noto-fonts
    ubuntu_font_family
    unifont
  ];

  fontconfig = {
    antialias = true;
    defaultFonts = {
      serif = [ "Ubuntu" ];
      sansSerif = [ "Ubuntu" ];
      monospace = [ "Ubuntu Source" ];
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Does the `Ubuntu` font have Katakana characters? If not, this is probably just a fall back. Does Kanji look sane? (By the way, funny choice of example instead of 日本語  :-) But I guess the point was to show broken Katakana.)

Comment: Kanji also appears in the same manner. I tried going to Google Docs and experimenting with a bunch of different fonts, including Noto Sans (which supposedly has support for CJK characters), but not matter what, the problem persists

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I didn't have any font with CJK support installed, apart from Unifont
Adding `noto-fonts-cjk-sans` package solved the problem